# "End-of-central-directory signature not found" after downloading zip file from my website

Tags: php, zip, nearlyfreespeech

I have a zip file named `filename.zip`. I used FileZilla to upload it to `/home/protected` directory on my website, hosted by NearlyFreeSpeech.net.

Recently, when I tried downloading the zip file and opening it by running `unzip filename.zip` in the terminal, I run into this error:

```
Archive:  filename.zip
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of filename.zip or
        filename.zip.zip, and cannot find filename.zip.ZIP, period.
```

Before last week or so, I could download the file from my website and unzip it without a problem.

I can unzip the file before copying it to my website.

I cannot unzip the copy of the file I download afterward.

Here is the PHP that handles the download.

```
$file = "path/to/file";

if(file_exists($file)){
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/zip');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: '.filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    fclose($handle);

} else {
    echo('File does not exist');
}
```

Why can I no longer properly unzip the zip files I downloaded?

Comment: Use FileZilla to retrieve the file: is it corrupted ? If so, the issue is when you upload the file (was not in binary mode ?). If not, the issue seems to be in the php script (but I don't see any obvious issue).

Comment: @DavidDuponchel the file is not corrupt when I download it thru FileZilla

Comment: Your code works on my machine (I can download a zip file and decompress it afterward). Do you test with this code exactly or is a part of a bigger php script ? "Before last week or so": did something change ?

Comment: It's part of a bigger script, but I changed nothing for the past few weeks, or the months before then

Comment: Could you try with a temporary page containing just this code ?